# Was I Hired Because of my Race?

Tags: hiring

Six months ago, I was hired at a company whose business is to provide IT services to other companies. Two other people were hired with me at the same time, another white guy and a Hmong guy. They sent us to work for their client, a rather large company of about 4000 people.

We have biweekly meetings from everyone in our company who works for this particular client, about 50 employees in total. The meetings are all remote now, but the first few were all in person. The two other new hires and myself were literally the only non-Indian people in these meetings.

I realize there is no definite answer to this question unless you are in the HR department my company, but is it LIKELY they hired us just for political reasons or reasons of diversity? I know it's nice to have a job when the unemployment is in double digits, but I just don't feel "right" about it. I'll probably start looking for a new job somewhere else if this is the reason I was hired.

Comment: Would you feel better if you were hired for your looks? The hiring process is not objective and involves a lot of things that are non-quantifiable. This is most likely the wrong thing to focus on. Change your goals to something that doesn't depend on someone's feelings and make it objective and measurable.

Comment: Is the client indian?

Comment: Are the people you are identifying as Indian - actually working from India?  Or is everyone working out of the same country as yourself?

Comment: We would have to know what country this is in.  In the US for example (and many countries) it's utterly normal to (have to, legally, be forced to by law) hire different "flavors" of people.  And then, in regions where there are absolutely no such laws, it's also completely common that some owner may (for whatever reason) want to hire only tall, short, etc people and/or a mix of people. For better or worse, this is completely unsurprising, normal and an everyday thing.

Comment: Wouldn't hiring you for diversity reasons be a good thing? Why would this make you want to leave?

Comment: It seems that you personally feel that you don't fit in with the culture of the company due to your race, that is a very different thing to questioning the hiring practices of your employer. If you feel you are able to complete the duties of your role sufficiently, then I would suggest that the companies hiring process seems to have worked, although that doesn't mean this company is the right cultural fit for you given the feelings you describe.

Comment: @joeqwerty Would you like to be known as "the diversity hire"?

Comment: I don't consider that a bad thing, so I wouldn't have a problem with it.

Comment: Did they interview you? Do a background check? Are you actually doing the job you were hired to do? Then you were hired because they thought you were qualified. I’m guessing nobody grabbed you off the street and said they wanted to pay you a full time salary to just sit there and be non-Indian.

Comment: @joeqwerty then to spell that out: many people prefer to be hired for their skills in the job than for how they look. That kind of meritocracy is a common ideal. Being hired for the optics can also imply that they have no faith in your skills and rather want to present you around rather than have you do actual work. At the very least it can be perceived as such. So there can be clear reasons to leave when assuming one was hired for those reasons. Not to mention that it can be considered racist and many people do not want to support racism.

Comment: @joeqwerty Which motivation exactly is OP's is likely irrelevant here (perhaps some weird XY problem aside), I just spelled out a few so it's hopefully clear that it's easy to see that as a problem and wanting to leave.

Comment: This sounds like a case of "Impostor Syndrome" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome

Answer (score 5):

I guess a team of more than 50 people, all appearing to be Indian might indeed give a strange impression at some clients. So I think you indeed may partly have been hired for political/diversity reasons.

However I really don't understand why you have such problem with it. People get hired all the time because of (family) connections, because they look good, are a smooth talker or because their parents could afford to send them to a fancy university. This time you get a (little) break.

I think you are being a bit immature if you want to quit your job for this reason.

Comment: What is immature about having ideals and trying to live by them? There is a lot of assumptions in this answer (leaving without another job, getting hired via family connections or because of good looks being 'okay' for everyone etc.)